# Question regarding eternal kakola narak from which no escape is possible

Tags: rebirth, naraka, pralaya

TIL there is a naraka called Kakola Narak from which one cannot escape by reincarnating.

I read on several sources that there is a narak called Kakola Narak (black poison) after reaching which the soul never reincarnated again (no escape from there). Would like some discussion here on this. Isn't it true that souls are eternal and after mahapralaya the universe is dissolved, so how is it possible that the soul never reincarnated after going to that place?

Comment: "several sources" is not a source. Please list an actual scriptural source.

Comment: Agni Purana mentions it